# tomcat7 fail to start inside Ubuntu Docker container

Tags: tomcat, ubuntu, tomcat7, docker

**The initial situation**

In Ubuntu (14.04 / 14.10) a ran the following commands:

```
apt-get update && apt-get install tomcat7
service tomcat7 start
```

On the one hand I tried this in a VirtualBox VM and tomcat7 startet as expected:

```
vagrant init hashicorp/precise32
vagrant up
```

On the other hand I tried this inside a Docker container, started as shown here:

```
sudo docker run -it --name tomcattest ubuntu bash
```

**The problem**

There the *service tomcat7 start* command outputs [fail]. Nevertheless tomcat is running, but */var/log/tomcat7/catalina.out* says following:

```
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/common], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/server], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared/classes], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/share/tomcat7/shared], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:40 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 514 ms
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu)
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:41 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/ROOT
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:42 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Apr 16, 2015 5:52:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 1150 ms
```

**explanation searched**

Could anybody exlain the different behavior and tell me if it is possible to install tomcat7 the easy way via apt-get inside a docker container without warnings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**The solution**

The tomcat startup script needs some special privileges. Concrete it needs to check all running processes, to verify itself is running. You can give the Docker container following privilege in order to make the tomcat start script exiting with success:

```
sudo docker run --cap-add SYS_PTRACE -it ubuntu bash
```

The important option is *--cap-add SYS_PTRACE*, all other options may vary. There is (at least one) an issue discussing this problem on docker github:

https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/6800

**subsequent problems**

Nevertheless I've found no way to set this privilege for the docker build of an image. My ultimate goal is to run a docker build which executes an Ansible playbook inside. The build just fails because of the service start, which I won't take out of the playbook. I'll make further investigations, but possible solutions are welcome.

Comment: Nice catch, more complete than my answer. +1

Comment: @Thomas Steinbach: did you find a way to fix it in `Dockerfile` itself?

Comment: @Arpit - seems there is no such command line argument for `docker run` yet. See [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/)

Comment: In docker-compose.yml there is configuration option cap_add. I have tried with - ALL and now service starts with Done in log, but still fails somewhere later. I can not locate what else is missing. How to debug this? Anyway , there is a workaround, to add addition to the command with example && tail -f /var/log/tomcat/catalina.out. This is a solution, except that you maybe loose direct control of service process below docker

Comment: @Arpit - a bit late but you have linked the `docker build` reference. See the `docker run` [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options)

Answer (score 1):

[This article](http://blog.frankel.ch/from-vaadin-to-docker-a-novices-journey) reports the same error (for Tomcat8, but it should apply for Tomcat7 as well):

> I have no idea why, but it seems Tomcat 8 on Ubuntu is not configured in any meaningful way. Everything is available but we need some symbolic links here and there as well as creating the temp directory. This translates into the following instruction in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN ln -s /var/lib/tomcat8/common $CATALINA_HOME/common && \\
    ln -s /var/lib/tomcat8/server $CATALINA_HOME/server && \\
    ln -s /var/lib/tomcat8/shared $CATALINA_HOME/shared && \\
    ln -s /etc/tomcat8 $CATALINA_HOME/conf && \\
    mkdir $CATALINA_HOME/temp
```

But the actual reason is probably in [this question](https://serverfault.com/a/658973/783)

> `CATALINA_BASE` et al. only get set in `/etc/init.d/tomcat8`.
>   In the docker image, that service doesn't get initialized as it does in a full VM.

Comment: For what I've read, the "meaning" of this layout is to have only one "/usr/share/tomcat8", but possibly multiple tomcat 8 instances and one "/var/lib/tomcat-instance-name" for each.